# Unexpected element when editing Standalone.xml

Tags: jboss, ibm-mq, spring-jms, jboss-eap-6

I'm trying ton configure a JMS MQueue on JBoss but
when I add an admin-object to the standalone.xml file :

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
                <archive>
                    wmq.jmsra.rar
                </archive>
                ...
                <admin-objects>
                    <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:jboss/resources/jms/MyQueueName" use-java-context="true" pool-name="MyQueuePool">
                        <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">
                            AAAA
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="baseQueueName">
                            BBBB
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                </admin-objects>
```

I'm getting the following error :

> Message: JBAS014789: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1}config-property' encountered
>
> Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[587,74]

Important points :

- There are other `admin-object` already existing.
- The XML is formatted correctly.
- I'm getting this error when trying to start my server.
- I'm using JBoss Entreprise Application Platform 6.3.3.GA
- [587,74] references the `admin-object` I'm trying to add.

Comment: What is the version of your JBoss instance exactly?

Comment: @TT. JBoss Entreprise Application Platform **6.3.3.GA**

Comment: Which line is 587? And what's on position 74?

Comment: @simas_ch **[587,74]** references the `admin-object` I'm trying to add.

Comment: Can you try to remove the `id` attribute of the `<resource-adapter>` element? I'm not seeing it anywhere else in examples online, and you define that in the `<archive>` anyway.

Comment: @TT. There are 6 other `admin-object` already defined in my Standalone.xml file, and they are working fine despite that file structure (the `id` attribute placed in the `<resource-adapter>`) so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Sad that there aren't any details on the `<admin-objects>` element in the [IronJacamar reference](http://www.ironjacamar.org/doc/userguide/1.2/en-US/html_single/index.html). Perhaps you could manually verify your standalone against the XSD? Perhaps some tool could point out more clearly what's wrong with the XML?

Comment: Perhaps it's the `use-java-context` and `pool-name` attributes that are invalid? Just blindly guessing...

Answer (score 0):

See Procedure 24.8. Deploy the Resource Adapter Manually:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Deploy_the_WebSphere_MQ_Resource_Adapter.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "Unexpected element" problem by duplicating a "<connection-definition" block.
The issue was duplicate pool-name attribute in several blocks.
By changing one of the pool name it solves the problem.